# Future Implied Price from Option Implied Distribution

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, volatility-smile

Been reading on option implied distributions and understand that this can be transformed into a confidence interval/fan chart showing the implied future price.

Was wondering how I could go about doing so from the PDF which i have calculated as below from the second differentials of the underlying's Call Price after interpolating its implied vol.

[image]

Understand that the above would have to be recreated across the term structure and in some studies, the forward price of underlying can be taken as the mean but what i struggle is extracting the S.D to create the Confidence Interval/Fan Chart.

Hence, was wondering if there was any way to do so?

Off the top of my head would be to tighten up my strikes and work outwards from the 100% strike to get the total probabilities of 68%/95%/99.7% and use the following strikes as my 1/2/3 s.d proxy.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you have a pdf to begin with, then you can produce prediction intervals by obtaining their end points directly as quantiles of the distribution. E.g. the 80% interval is $(q_{10\%},q_{90\%})$. It makes more sense to do this then to extract sd first and apply the normal approximation to obtain confidence intervals, not least because the normal approximation may be poor.